# How can I use a custom DNS server?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I have a DNS server running on `172.18.0.2` and I want to use it as my DNS server. I went into the network manager and set up my connection:

[image]

The server works:

```
$ host test 172.18.0.2
Using domain server:
Name: 172.18.0.2
Address: 172.18.0.2#53
Aliases: 

test has address 93.184.216.34
```

but Ubuntu isn't using it:

```
$ host test
Host test not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

How can I get the expected behavior?

Ubuntu version 19.04.

`systemd-resolve --status` output:

```
Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 172.18.0.2
         DNS Servers: 172.18.0.2
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

`dig host` output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.6-Ubuntu <<>> host
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 39546
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;host.              IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: dim. déc. 15 21:08:57 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 33
```

Comment: You haven't specified your Ubuntu version. But, what is the portion of the output of the command `systemd-resolve --status` that lists the DNS Servers used by your system?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Ubuntu 19.04. For `systemd-resolve`, the "Global" section doesn't mention my DNS settings, but the section headed "Link 2 (enp0s31f6)" does include the line `Current DNS Server: 172.18.0.2`. Should I include the whole output in the question?

Comment: Are there any other DNS server mentioned there? Please, post only the portion for active link ("Link 2 (enp0s31f6)").

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Updated.

Comment: Will you please provide the output of 'dig host'? I wonder if you're getting hamstrung by the stub resolver.

Comment: @ofperfection Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The surest way to make everything cooperate with your custom DNS will be to use your own TLD, such as .local or similar, and making that a search domain in your /etc/resolv.conf. That way, when you search 'host' it will automatically know to search the .local domain. DNS was designed around domains.

If you really don't want to use a TLD, perhaps an entry in `/etc/hosts` would suit your use case. This would map 'host' directly to the resource you intend.

Here's one method for manually specifying name servers if you're currently getting getting funny business due to the systemd stub resolver (it looks like this could be the case per the dig output you provided, and I've had issues in the past with it. Back all configs up before making any changes, and be aware this assumes an unmodified /etc/nsswitch.conf):

The below command will indicate whether your /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink:

```
kano@:~$ file -s /etc/resolv.conf 
/etc/resolv.conf: symbolic link to ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

To test this method, back up your original resolv.conf symlink in the event you need to roll back (to rollback, simply rename the backup /etc/resolv.conf, you shouldn't need to reboot for any of this to take effect). Modifying the existing symlink will not work:

```
kano@:~$ mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
```

Finally, specify the desired nameserver and search values in your new, custom /etc/resolv.conf using the text editor of your choice (my AWS instance /etc/resolv.conf contents below, you'll need to tailor this to your environment).

```
    kano@:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
    nameserver 172.31.0.2  
    search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

If this sorts the name resolution issue (and you can verify via `dig host` that it is querying your specified nameserver instead of the stub resolver  127.0.0.53), I'd consider adding the immutable attribute(you can check attributes with `lsattr filename`) to your /etc/resolv.conf to prevent upgrades/systemd from overwriting it via:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

You will need to remove the immutable attribute via chattr -i to modify this file in the future.

Comment: Was hoping to get away without modifying config files manually. Is this just a bug in Ubuntu that using the network manager isn't sufficient for this purpose?

Comment: I'm seeing now that I unintentionally asked for `dig host` instead of `dig test`, which led to my initial potentially excessive troubleshooting recommendation. Would you mind updating the output to reflect `dig test`, along with `getent hosts test`? 

I'd like to see how a ping fails as well, if possible. Sorry about that!

Will your typical DNS entries have a TLD like test.lan or similar?

Comment: `dig test` produces the same output as `dig host` (it lists the DNS as 127.0.0.53). `getent hosts test` produces no output. `ping test` results in `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Comment: Curiously, setting the DNS in the network manager has *some* effect on the system since no network programs can resolve hosts like `google.com` anymore (Firefox, curl, ping), it's just that they also can't resolve the `test` domain that my local DNS knows about, even though `host test 172.18.0.2` confirms that the DNS server is up.

Comment: Do you have an entry with a domain extension to test, test.lan or similar? Assuming you configured your own DNS server, what software are you using(I.e. bind?)

Comment: The DNS server is dnsmasq inside a docker container running on the same machine, using docker's "bridge" network so it has its own IP. I tried earlier with `test.local` instead of `test` and got the same behavior.